# Acumatica: what it the correct way to over right release so that base happens first

Tags: acumatica

Good day

What is the correct way to change the below Release function to: first do the base function and only do your code?
When you use the built-in Acumatice "Override method"(that can be found when editing code) you get the following:

```
namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
    public class ARPaymentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARPaymentEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers
        public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
        [PXOverride]
        public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
        {         
           //Normally you will add your code here.
            return baseMethod(adapter);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

If you wanted the base to run fist and then you wanted your code after if would somthing like this:

```
namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
    // Acuminator disable once PX1016 ExtensionDoesNotDeclareIsActiveMethod extension should be constantly active
    public class ARPaymentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARPaymentEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers
        public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
        [PXOverride]
        public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
        {

            baseMethod(adapter);
            // your code here.
            return;

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Question: What should I put as the return?
If I use null it gives a return nextstep error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
{
    IEnumerable result = baseMethod(adapter);
    
    // your code here
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I would add TransactionScope to make sure that everything either happens all together or doesn't happen at all to avoid any broken data in the system